# Como fazer uma "ampliação" de um arquivo em outro arquivo no visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio

Estou com alguns projetos em python, e para facilitar o meu trabalho, eu faço "sub-arquivos", ou seja, eu crio outros arquivos e "compilo" eles durante a execução do programa pela função: "exec". Mas me deparei com um problema, não consigo fazer o VSC "usar" variáveis do "arquivo mãe".
De maneira mais simples, seria como fazer uma divisão de um mesmo arquivo.
Teria alguma maneira, no visual studio code, de fazer ele considerar um conjunto de arquivos como um só arquivo?

Comment: Eu não entendi a pergunta. Você quer fazer isso https://ideone.com/RJ8nNn ler vários arquivos juntar os textos na memória e executar o script resultante?

Comment: Isso mesmo, !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se quer juntar o conteúdo de vários arquivos texto na memória use uma stream de texto [`io.StringIO()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO).

O conteúdo de `io.StringIO()` pode escrito com o método herdado [`io.TextIOBase.write()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.write) ou com a função embutida [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#print) configurando o parâmetro `file` com a stream.

O conteúdo de `io.StringIO()` pode ser lido em uma string com o método [`io.StringIO.getvalue()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO.getvalue).

Para executar um código dinamicamente use a função embutida [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#exec).

O exemplo abaixo pressupõe o uso de três arquivos de texto que juntos compõe um script:

**`script.py1`**

```
texto = 'Hello, world!'
```

**`script.py2`**

```
def foo(s):
  print(f'foo {s}')
```

**`script.py3`**

```
foo(texto)
```

O script python que lerá os três arquivos, juntará seus conteúdos e executará dinamicamente o script gerado:

```
import io

#Inicializa stream de texto a ser preenchida com conteúdo dos arquivos.
f = io.StringIO()

#Abre, lê e junta os conteúdos dos arquivos na memória.
with open('script.py1') as script:
  print(*script.readlines(), file=f)
with open('script.py2') as script:
  print(*script.readlines(), file=f)
with open('script.py3') as script:
  print(*script.readlines(), file=f)

#Obtem uma string com o conteúdo unificado dos arquivos.
arquivo = f.getvalue()
#Fecha a stream.
f.close()


#Executa o arquivo no contexto local.
exec(arquivo, globals(), locals())               #foo Hello, world!
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/JuntarArquivos#main.py)</sup>